# Injecting one service into another results in error: "must be an instance of ..., none given"

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I created a Listener Service to listen for the Login so that I could perform some database operations after login. I'm trying to inject another service into my Listener but I'm getting a fatal error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   WX\ExchangeBundle\Service\SecurityListener::__construct() must be an
>   instance of WX\ExchangeBundle\Service\UserService, none given

config.yml:

```
services:
    wxexchange_user_service:
        class:      WX\ExchangeBundle\Service\UserService
        arguments:  [@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager]
    wxexchange_login_listener:
        class:      WX\ExchangeBundle\Service\SecurityListener
        arguements: [@wxexchange_user_service]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

SecurityListener:

```
namespace WX\ExchangeBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use WX\ExchangeBundle\Service\UserService;

class SecurityListener
{
    protected $userService;

    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $lastLogin = new DateTime();

        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        $this->userService->setLastLogin($user, $lastLogin);
    }
}
```

I've already tried clearing the cache, but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: I have changed your question's title by removing the 'Symfony2' tag from it. [Titles without tags in them are appreciated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/244357), Stack Overflow already has a good tag system for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your `config.yml`:

```
arguements: [@wxexchange_user_service]
```

must be:

```
arguments: [@wxexchange_user_service]
```

(note the 'e' in arguements)

Because of this, the `SecurityListener` is instantiated without any arguments, but it requires an object of type `UserService`. That is why you get the error message.

Comment: Bingo. Now I know why I should've kept the Notepad++ spellchecker enabled. Would have saved me an hour today. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's mostly the small typo's that sometimes can take hours to find... I must say that using a more advanced IDE helps a lot. I really suggest switching to one, instead of Notepad!

Comment: use NetBeans, it's free and it works very well. It also supports Symfony.

Comment: NetBeans is a good (and free) IDE indeed, I use PHPStorm (not free) myself. Just as NetBenas, it has great support for Symfony.